# Сложение цифр числа

Tags: c

Нужно записать каждую цифру числа в массив, а после сложить их.

```
int n = 87654321;
int size = IntCount(n);//к-во цифр в числе
int array[size],i;     // да, VLA лучше не использовать но так проще

int stepen = size-1,   // степень в какую возносим, самый старший разряд- [0]
    summa=0;
    for(i=0;i<size;i++)
    {
        array[i] = n/(int)pow(10,stepen)%10;   //получаем каждую цифру и в массив
        summa=summa + array[i];
        stepen--;                              // уменьшаем степень
    }
    printf("Сумма = %d",summa);
```

В результате сложения выдает какую-то чушь, хотя цифры в массиве верные. Возможно проблема  в модификаторе, но я не понимаю почему.

Comment: @Hardc0re  Вы не получили ответ на свой вопрос, почему ваш код не работает.:)

Comment: @Hardc0re  Более того ваша проблема не воспроизводится, так что вам следует показать минимально проверяемый код, демонстрирующий проблему.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для получения разряда нужно использовать операцию получения остатка при делении на 10

```c
int n = 87654321;
int size = IntCount(n);//к-во цифр в числе
int array[size];

int summa = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
  array[i] = n % 10;//получаем последний разряд
  n /= 10; // убираем последний разряд
  summa += array[i];
}
printf("Сумма = %d",summa);
```

Comment: Так в чем ошибка в исходном коде вопроса?

Comment: @VladfromMoscow вероятно, здесь `(int)pow(10,stepen)`. Производится округление вниз, а нужно до ближайшего целого. Тогда из 9.9999999999 мы получим не 9, а, как и ожидали, 10

Comment: 8   Это неверное заключение, так как автор вопроса утверждает, что цифры в массив заносятся правильные, и я сам не смог воспроизвести проблему для заданного числа.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Я уже давно не верю утверждениям, а верю коду. Вы же сами видите, что если в массиве все значения правильны, то сумма посчитаться ошибочно не может. Значит, ошибка, все таки, в заполнении массива. Это место одно из кандидатов на ошибку. Второй кандидат здесь `IntCount(n)`

Comment: Поэтому ваш ответ не является ответом на вопрос. Вы не выяснили причину ошибки. Надо было потребовать от автора показать минимальный проверяемый пример, демонстрирующий проблему. А так вы просто предложили другое решение, а вопрос остался без ответа.

Comment: Это уже типичная демагогия...